# Does MongoDB support passing `Infinity` into `.limit()`

Tags: mongodb

This is mostly an academic question, but a colleague and I are disagreeing on whether Mongo (through MeteorJS which uses `EJSON` which does serializes fine) supports passing `Infinity` as a query limit. I've been passing it in some cases with no apparent issues while he is concerned about using it because Mongo's docs don't clearly call out whether it's supported or not. I even tried using it on the Mongo CLI and it worked as expected (`db.collection.find().limit(Infinity).count()`). And there doesn't seem to be any information about this specific question anywhere online that either of us could find. I know Mongo isn't technically JS, but it's syntax certainly is, which leads me to assume it uses a JS parsing engine, which leads me to believe `Infinity` is supported implicitly.

Comment: It's not strictly academic, though, if a limit argument was optional you could write .limit(limitParam || Infinity). Of course, since the docs clearly state 0 works that way and say nothing of Infinity, zero is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#supported-values) for `limit`:

> The behavior of `limit()` is undefined for values less than -2<sup>31</sup> and greater than 2<sup>31</sup>.

I read that to indicate that `Infinity` is not supported.

Comment: Isn't that the normal range for JS integers? `Infinity` is a special case number in JS, but still a number.

Comment: @webbower JS doesn't natively have a concept of integers. The limitation is likely from the server's C++ implementation using a signed int internally.

Comment: It does have a Number type. Whether the underlying engine supports the special case of `Infinity` or not (along with other special JS numbers like `NaN`) is the question. There are tests written the Mongo source to test for the `Infinity` value (not sure what the tests are without diving in) https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/search?utf8=✓&q=Infinity&type=

Comment: @webbower Even though it works, the docs are clear that the behavior of using `Infinity` is undefined. I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 21):

```
limit(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
```

or

```
limit(0)
```

A limit() value of 0 (i.e. .limit(0)) is equivalent to setting no limit.

[for more info](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#supported-values)

Comment: throws error. has to be positive